# Selenium IDE - Cannot select text in an Autocomplete/ Unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE and trying to click an autocomplete item in a field. I am unable to find a way to click the element. When you click the item it populates the next field. I have been playing around with this for two days and cannot figure it out. If I could get the mouse cursor in the field, then press down followed by enter it would probably work. I tried:

```
<td>clickAt</td>
<td>id=txtCategory</td>
<td></td>

<td>keyPress</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>\40</td>

<td>keyPress</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>\13</td>
```

but it didn't work. I have tried using focus and/or blur with sendkeys, keydown, and keypress but I couldn't seem to get that to work either. There is also a hoverstate when you mouseover the autocomplete word. I couldn't find a way to access that state in selenium nor do I know if I need to. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is a link to the picture of the field I am trying to click while being inspected by firebug, along with a few of the things i was trying in Selenium IDE.

I have also tried:

For Value was I supposed to put 'Customer check bounced'? I can get the text in the field but without actually clicking the Autocompleted text the next field will not populate. Here is what I tried:

```
<td>typeKeys</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>Customer check bounced</td>



<td>fireEvent</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>focus</td>



<td>fireEvent</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>blur</td>


<td>keyPress</td>
<td>css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all</td>
<td>\13</td>
```

[image]

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find the solution to my problem after 2 days of searching. You can locate items and click them using the html. Here are the Steps I used:

```
1. Click into the field to cause the autocomplete to fire

<td>clickAt</td>
<td>id=txtCategory</td>
<td></td>

2. Mouseover the field that contains the autocompleted word I need to click

<td>mouseOver</td>
<td>//html/body/ul/li/a/b</td>
<td></td>

3. Click the autocomplete item I need to click in order for the next field to function

<td>click</td>
<td>//html/body/ul/li/a/</td>
<td></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using Selenium IDE and have been trying to select elements generated from google place autocomplete, the following script works fine for me, I hope it will help.

```
<tr>
    <td>sendKeys</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>48 Westlawn Dr.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>\40</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>keyDown</td>
    <td>id=address</td>
    <td>\13</td>
</tr>
```

1. `sendKeys` will fire dropdown menu
2. `keyDown` jump between selections
3. Last `keyDown` is to send enter key

The trick is all operations performed on the same element.

Reference: http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2013/06/selenium-keydown-command-to-select.html

Answer (score 0):

Used typekeys command in selenium for autocomplete command. 
This is a convenience method for calling keyDown, keyUp, keyPress for every character in the specified string; this is useful for dynamic UI widgets (like auto-completing combo boxes) that require explicit key events.

```
typeKeys| css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all | value
```

Comment: For Value was I supposed to put 'Customer check bounced'? I can get the text in the field but without actually clicking the Autocompleted text the next field will not populate. Here is what I tried: 
`typeKeys| css=.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all+.ui-corner-all | Customer check bounced`